# How can I make Ctrl+M an event that brings up a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm mf = new Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm();
    mf.Show();
}
```

It shows the target form correctly. But instead of using a button click, I want to use <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> to show this form. If the users types <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> again, I want to close the the form.

How can I do this?

Edit:

This is what i did wich is working :

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "M")
            {
                Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm mf = new Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm();
                mf.Show();
            }
        }
```

In the constructor of Form1 i added:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

So now when i click on Ctrl+M i see the new Form.
What i need now is how to make that if i click again on Ctrl+M it will close the new Form.
Maybe using a flag ?

Edit:

This is what i did now:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "M")
            {

                    if (mf == null)
                    {
                        mf = new Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm();
                        mf.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mf.Close();
                        this.Invalidate();
                    }
            }
        }
```

But even doing this.Invalidate(); i don't see the new Form closed.
But if im using put a breakpoint on the mf.Close(); and step into(F11) i see it close when making continue.

Why it dosen't close without using a breakpoint ?

Comment: you can check if (mf == null) then open.. else close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add onKeyPress or onKeyDown 
and check if  Ctrl+M were pressed

```
private void OnKeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e) 
if (((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control) 
    && (e.KeyChar == 'M'|| e.KeyChar == 'm'))
{
        mf.Show();
}
```

Comment: all you can do is from the parent form to open the child form using the keyDown.. and then in the child form add again the keyDown event and check if the user hit ctrl+m and close it

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `InputBindings` object. I think in your case, probably best to put that at the `Window` level (Window.InputBindings). More information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in 2 ways.

1. If you are using a GUI interface, add a `MenuItem` control on your Menu, and put the `Shortcut` property to <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>  then double click the `MenuItem` to edit the code, then call your `launchMagnifier()` function.   If you do NOT want your menu to show, just set the `visible` properties to false.  This keeps the menu hidden if you do not want it, yet still holds the functionality.
2. If you do not want the MenuItem, you can catch keys that are pressed in your form.  So in your frmMain.cs form, add an event to capture keys, then when <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> is pressed, invoke `launchMagnifier()`

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do that.

On your form set the KeyPreview Property to true

Then add an OnKeyPress or OnKeyDown event handler to the form.

In that test for Ctrl-M and show / destroy the form and set handled (e.Handled) to true.

Any other keypress will be passed on to the currently focused control as it hasn't been handled.